# R split: Reuse the first ith element in a vector to make split equal

Tags: r, split

I want to split a vector into subvectors such that overlapping of elements is only in two neighbouring subvectors which this `r` function handles well.

```
blocks <- function(len, ov, n) {

  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, len), seq(len-ov+1, n, len))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + len - 1, n)

  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}

vec = 1:17 # here is my vector
len = 5 # here is the length of each vector
ov = ceiling(len/2) #here is the number of overlapping element in each vector
b <- blocks(len, ov, length(vec)) # is data frame that set the starting and ending of each block
with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends)) # here is function that prints out the overlapping split

## here is the output below 
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7

#[[3]]
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10

#[[4]]
#[1]  8  9 10 11 12

#[[5]]
#[1] 11 12 13 14 15

#[[6]]
#[1] 13 14 15 16 17
```

But if the length of each block is 6 the last block will not be up to 6 as can be seen below

```
vec = 1:17 # here is my vector
len = 6 # here is the length of each vector
ov = ceiling(len/2) #here is the number of overlapping element in each vector
b <- blocks(len, ov, length(vec)) # is data frame that set the starting and ending of each block
with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends)) # here is function that prints out the overlapping split

## the block of 6 that I get
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

#[[3]]
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12

#[[4]]
#[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15

#[[5]]
#[1] 13 14 15 16 17
```

One can see that the `5th` subvector is 5 elements while the vector is exhausted.

**What I want**

I want each subvector to be comprised of the same number of elements including the last subvector such that the last subvector to use the firs ith element(s) to add up to its number of elements. In this case, I have `5` elements instead of `6` in the last subvector, then the first element of the vector should be used.

```
## the block of 6 that I want 
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

#[[3]]
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12

#[[4]]
#[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15

#[[5]]
#[1] 13 14 15 16 17 1
```

Comment: What's the logic that the additional element is `1`? Could it also be `NA`?

Comment: No, it can not be `NA`. It can only be a wrap up from the original vector to make the number of elements in the last subvector to be equals to `len`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the sequences continue beyond the maximum of the vector and use modulos. In `blocks2`, `st`arting points of the sequences are being found using modulo `ov`; we get the second column values by adding the vector lengths. Second column should only exceed maximum of `vec` one single time, thus we subset by boolean `cumsum`.

Later in the `apply` we subset `vec` on modulo `max(vec) + 1`; and add the remainders of integer multiplication `%/%`.

```
blocks2 <- function(vec, len) {
  ov <- ceiling(len/2)
  f <- function(vec, len, ov) {
    st <- (vec - 1) %% ov == 0
    b <- cbind(vec[st], vec[st] + len - 1)
    b[cumsum(b[,2] >= max(vec)) <= 1, ]
  }
  res <- apply(f(vec, len, ov), 1, function(x) {
    r <- x[1]:x[2] %% (max(vec) + 1)
    add <- x[1]:x[2] %/% (max(vec) + 1)
    r + add
  })
  unname(split(res, col(res)))
}
```

**Length four:**

```
blocks2(vec, 4)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3 4 5 6
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 5 6 7 8
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]  7  8  9 10
# 
# [[5]]
# [1]  9 10 11 12
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 11 12 13 14
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 13 14 15 16
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 15 16 17  1
```

**Length five:**

```
blocks2(vec, 5)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 13 14 15 16 17
```

**Length six:**

```
blocks2(vec, 6)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 13 14 15 16 17  1
```

Comment: The idea of setting `ov` should be overruled by `ov = ceiling(len/2)` please. I want `ov` automated from `len`

Comment: @DanielJames Then we take it up in the function, see edits.

Comment: Your answer is great, but when `len = 5` subvector 3 started at `7` instead of `6`. this made the `6th` element to only occur once in the split

Answer (score 1):

You can try a for loop?

```
vec = 1:17 # here is my vector
len = 6 # here is the length of each vector
ov = ceiling(len/2) #here is the number of overlapping element in each vector


tmp <- list()
for(i in 1:len){
  mm <- gl(len, ov)
  mm_start <- which(mm == i)[1]
  mm_end <- mm_start+len-1
  
  if(length(vec) >= mm_end){
  tmp[[i]] <- vec[mm_start:mm_end]
  }else{
  tmp[[i]] <-  c(vec, vec[1:(mm_end-length(vec))])[mm_start:mm_end]
  }
}
tmp
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12

[[4]]
[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15

[[5]]
[1] 13 14 15 16 17  1

[[6]]
[1] 16 17  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: can it just stop when it made the last subvector complete? Apart from that, it works great.

Comment: which index has the last subvector? 5? Is it always 5? If so, include this line `if( i > 5) next`

Comment: No, it is not always `5`. try `len = 4

Comment: When I use `len = 4` I get four subvectors with the `4th` being `[1]  7  8  9 10`. the parent vector is nut exhausted at `10` but at `17`

Comment: hmmm and what is the expexted output, then? More than four subvectors?